# Cannot add provider hosted app: "The specified application identifier is invalid"

Tags: sharepoint-addin

My Sharepoint Online provider hosted app stopped working. 
I am running the app/add-in from IIS Express while debugging in VS.

I removed the app from the page, but when I tried to re-add it, I got:
"The specified application identifier [CLIENTID] is invalid or does not exist".

Then I went to the App Catalog and uploaded a new version of the same add-in.
But I still got the same error.

I then removed the app, and re-uploaded it, but I still got the same error.

Then I wanted to change the Client ID and Client secret (and later build and re-upload the app). 
I went to https://mycompany.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx and filled in the fields.
I clicked Generate on both Client Id and Client secret.
But on clicking Create, I got the error:
"Sorry, something went wrong"

I retried, but used the Examples (contoso.com) for App Domain and Redirect URL.
This time it was successful.

But I will probably not be able to use that registration... why doesn't it work with mycompany.com?

Is it a rights issue? I believe I am not an SP-Tenant admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registering the new client id failed because I had used mycompany.com as App domain. I changed it to localhost/port and then it worked.